# List options order and groups

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

I have a group of options from a new button like this:

[image]

I am not sure if six options are too much for the user. Perhaps it has too much cognitive load? Any suggestion?

Another question is: "Project" is the main button, and the other five (taks, incidence, meeting, file and note) are related to the project. Previously we had an only button for "Project" and the new button for the other five options. But we are thinking in put all of them together like I am showing in the sketch attached. What do you think is the best way?

Thanks and regards,
Alejandro.

Comment: If Project is the main action it should always be visible and not hidden behind a button. You said the other options are project related, does that mean they cant be used before creating a new project? I guess it would be fine to add the other options next to the "Create project" button as a "more options" icon (3 dots).

Comment: You could allow the users to customize the modules of the app they will/will not use.  If they will never use the "Task" capability then allow them to remove it from the UI.
Alternatively, you can order them based on how much the user has used them.  If they have 50 Notes, and only 3 Tasks, put the New Note button higher than the Tasks button.
You can also do some subtle coloring so that less used options are less saturated, and the most used option is bolded.

Comment: Then, in that case, these options shouldn't be clubbed. what is the use case of those options? How are they related to project? When I had first look at these options to me it felt that I can create new project/task/incidence/meeting/file or note.

Comment: Yes, that is right: you can create a new project/task/incidence/meeting or note. But the father of every task/incidence/meeting or note is a project....

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it's clear the other options fall under a project. Therefore, a multi-purpose "new" view may be ideal.

**New Button is Clicked**

Defaults to a new project screen:

[image: New Project]

**Drop Down for Additional Actions**

Select task, meeting, etc.

[image: New Task]

However, keep in mind the following when designing such a UI: *which actions will be performed most frequently?* Do you expect your users to be creating more projects than tasks? Design your UI around the quickest path to frequent user actions.

Comment: Thanks for your drawings and comments, Alan! What you ask at the end of your notes it's what makes me to doubt: we will create sometimes a project, but very frequently taks based in that project....

Comment: Here might be a simple solution. If a user is currently in a project, the "new" button defaults to task.

Comment: thanks, Alan. And what if I am in the main page and I want to create a new subtask and associate it to a project? Should I also put then "+" button in the main page? Regards, Alejandro.